# Django count persons by month and year

Tags: python, mysql, django, datetime

I've been debugging for I while but I can't get the right result.
In my django application I have extended the auth_user to add more fields:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Person(User):
    api_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    api_key = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Now, I want to count users by year and month according to the date they joined:

`Person.objects.annotate(year=TruncYear("date_joined"), month=TruncMonth("date_joined")).values("year", "month").annotate(count=Count("pk"))`

However, all I get is a count=1 for each user in the database without grouping them by year and month.

This is the actual query being executed:

```
SELECT CAST(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(`auth_user`.`date_joined`, 'UTC', 'Europe/Madrid'), '%Y-01-01 00:00:00') AS DATETIME) AS `year`, CAST(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(`auth_user`.`date_joined`, 'UTC', 'Europe/Madrid'), '%Y-%m-01 00:00:00') AS DATETIME) AS `month`, COUNT(`mt_api_app_person`.`user_ptr_id`) AS `count` FROM `mt_api_app_person` INNER JOIN `auth_user` ON (`mt_api_app_person`.`user_ptr_id` = `auth_user`.`id`) GROUP BY CAST(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(`auth_user`.`date_joined`, 'UTC', 'Europe/Madrid'), '%Y-01-01 00:00:00') AS DATETIME), CAST(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(`auth_user`.`date_joined`, 'UTC', 'Europe/Madrid'), '%Y-%m-01 00:00:00') AS DATETIME), `auth_user`.`date_joined` ORDER BY `auth_user`.`date_joined` DESC
```

All count=1 seem to occur because of the `GROUP BY [...] 'auth_user'.'date_joined'` which is grouping the entries by the whole datetime and not just month and year.

Any clues of what's happening here? If I do the same query but with the User I get what I want.

```
SELECT CAST(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(`auth_user`.`date_joined`, 'UTC', 'Europe/Madrid'), '%Y-%m-01 00:00:00') AS DATETIME) AS `month`, COUNT(`auth_user`.`id`) AS `count` FROM `auth_user` GROUP BY CAST(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(`auth_user`.`date_joined`, 'UTC', 'Europe/Madrid'), '%Y-%m-01 00:00:00') AS DATETIME) ORDER BY NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [TruncMonth and TruncYear](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/database-functions/)

```
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth, TruncYear

Person.objects.annotate(month=TruncMonth('date_joined')).values('month').annotate(total=Count('pk'))
Person.objects.annotate(year=TruncYear('date_joined')).values('year').annotate(total=Count('pk'))
```

Comment: It is not working. It returns count=1 for each user instead of grouping it by month and year and returning counts like for example, count=251

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems to have a typo. You are using `TruncYear` for month and year, that is why you are getting only one value and that is for the year.

For month:

```
Person.objects.annotate(month=TruncMonth("date_joined")).values("month").annotate(count=Count("pk"))
```

For year:

```
Person.objects.annotate(year=TruncYear("date_joined")).values("year").annotate(count=Count("pk"))
```

Comment: You are right, I made a typo when copying here the query. But I did it correctly on Django. I corrected my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, but the same query on a different model worked just fine. Finally figured out this issue is cause from my model (in your case the `Person` model) has a default order_by set. If you clear the order by on the query it should work as expected.

```
Person.objects.annotate(year=TruncYear('date_joined')).values('year').annotate(total=Count('pk')).order_by()
```